# React router conditional redirect url based on async fetched data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a codesand box below which show the situation I have:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/sad-nash-x4n69

I have an object named `dataset` which can have zero, one or more versions. The component should show the latest version if `dataset` has any versions or show a default empty page. Because of this two conditions the component has two routes: `/dataset` and `/dataset/:version`:

If the dataset is empty I need the url route to `/dataset/overview` which should the basic info of the `dataset`.

If the dataset is not empty I need to redirect the route to `/dataset/${dataset.versions}` which will show the latest version data.

Meanwhile, the `DatasetView` Component has three tabs: `overview` `versions` `settings`. I hope the page will automatically redirect to `/dataset/overview` or `/dataset/:version/overview` depends on the `dataset.versions`.

But my code below have a bug: when the dataset has no versions, the route will change to `/dataset/overview/overview` but not `/dataset/overview`. Hope some one can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @dev_junwen's solution probably works, I'd like to provide a simpler one and look into the reason why your original router didn't work.

In your code, the router has a param `version` that could be omitted. Since you didn't specify the param as optional, the app always expect the slug following `dataset` to be `version` and append another `/overview` even when it's not needed.

By setting it as optional at the `Router` level, the app should work.

```
  <Route path={["/dataset/:version([0-9]+)?", "/dataset"]}>
```

In order for the existing routes inside the `DatassetComponent` component to work, I've added a regex to the `version` param so that it only matches digits.

See a working code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-beaver-c14kk

Comment: Wow, it works! This is a great solution. I just tried `<Route path={["/dataset/:version(\d+)", "/dataset"]}>` but failed.

Comment: @aisensiy Only url patterns `path-to-regexp` understands are valid in `React Router`. Use `\\d` instead of `\d` should work. See more at: https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/#path-to-regexp

Comment: I've tried with `:version?` as well and I couldn't make it work at that time. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: @dev_junwen Thanks! I've tried a few different ways around this and the regex way seems to be the most straightforward.

Comment: @aisensiy If you find any answers useful, could you please accept and upvote it? Thanks!

Comment: @ClairLin I did it! Sorry for do this sooo late.

Answer (score 1):

At first the question seems easy but it took me quite long to figure out how to do this! This is the only way I can think of right now. If there's some suggestions on how to improve the codes, feel free to submit a change request :)

**I cannot guarantee that this is the best way of doing this, but it works for your case.**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  NavLink,
  useRouteMatch,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const datasetWithVersions = {
  id: "dataset-with-versions",
  versions: 2,
  versionList: [
    {
      version: 1,
      size: 20001
    },
    {
      version: 2,
      size: 191232
    }
  ],
  name: "a-dataset-with-2-versions"
};

const datasetWithNoVerrsions = {
  id: "dataset-with-no-versions",
  versions: 0,
  name: "an-empty-dataset"
};

function loadDataset() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Math.random() >= 0.5) {
        console.log("loading dataset with versions....");
        resolve(datasetWithVersions);
      } else {
        console.log("loading dataset with no versions....");
        resolve(datasetWithNoVerrsions);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/dataset" component={DatassetComponent} />
          <Redirect to="/dataset" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

function DatassetComponent() {
  let [dataset, setDataset] = useState(null);
  const match = useRouteMatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    loadDataset().then(data => setDataset(data));
  }, []);

  if (!dataset) return <div>loading...</div>;

  const getURL = to => {
    if (dataset.versions) {
      return `${match.path}/${dataset.versions}/${to}`;
    }
    return `${match.path}/${to}`;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="navbar">
        <NavLink to={getURL("overview")} activeClassName="active">
          OverView
        </NavLink>
        {dataset.versions ? (
          <NavLink to={getURL("versions")} activeClassName="active">
            Versions
          </NavLink>
        ) : null}
        <NavLink to={getURL("settings")} activeClassName="active">
          Settings
        </NavLink>
      </div>

      <div className="content">
        <Switch>
          <Route path={getURL("versions")}>
            <div>Versions</div>
          </Route>
          <Route path={getURL("settings")}>
            <div>settings</div>
          </Route>
          <Route path={getURL("overview")}>
            <div>Overview for dataset {dataset.name}</div>
          </Route>
          <Redirect to={getURL("overview")} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-optional-path-demo-p50b4?fontsize=14

Comment: I like the behavior that redirecting url `/dataset/:version/overview` to a dataset with no version to `/dataset/overview`. This is sooo cool.